# on constructor theres is value but when I want use it on another function, it is zero (Android)

Tags: java, android, constructor

```
    double cal;
    double rcarbohydrate;
    double rfat;
    double rprotein;   

 public AdapterDB(double cal, double rcarbohydrate, double rfat, double rprotein, Context ctx)
          {
                this.cal = cal;
                this.rcarbohydrate = rcarbohydrate;
                this.rfat = rfat;
                this.rprotein = rprotein;
                this.context = ctx;
                DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper (context);

                Log.v("", "cal1 " + cal);   
                Log.v("", "cal1 " + rcarbohydrate);
                Log.v("", "cal1 " + rfat);
                Log.v("", "cal" + rprotein);
          }

          public void generateSomething()
          {
                 Log.i("", "cal2 " + cal);   
                 Log.i("", "cal2 " + rcarbohydrate);
                 Log.i("", "cal2 " + rfat);
                 Log.i("", "cal2 " + rprotein);
          }
```

it cannot get the value. cal1 get the value but cal2 is 0.0 why? Any idea how can I solve this? Thx. actually cal = 2500.00 rcarbohydrate = 350.50 rfat = 45.90 rprotein = 156.90

Comment: Are you sure you're calling `generateSomething()` on the same instance of the class?

Comment: One class, but how many instances of the class? Can you show how you call new AdapterDB(...) and generateSomething(). (see @Mocialov Boris's answer)

Comment: AdabterDB is constructor

Comment: Show\tell us how you are making a call to the constructor and method generateSomething()

Answer (score 3):

are you sure that datatypes are same .
could you try " this.cal " in constructor and see!

Comment: how you are getting instance of AdapterDB class                       AdapterDB db = new AdapterDB() or AdapterDB db = new AdapterDB( 12, 232, ....); ??

Comment: db = new AdapterDB (cal, rcarbohydrate, rfat, rprotein, getApplicationContext());

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to call constructor at some point in your program, say class **Test.java** like

```
AdapterDB adapterDB = new AdapterDB(val1, val2, val3, val4, context);
```

that means you create a new object adapterDB, which contains some values.

Now you are able to use this object by calling

```
adapterDB.someFunction();
```

or pass this object to another class(Activity), in android either by intent - intent.putExtra() as Parcelable object, but then you must modify your object class

and make sure that first - you create an object and second - you use it with the respect to the sequence of execution in your Activity (Android)

Comment: and try accessing cal2 using this.cal

Comment: still same zero for the result

Comment: Explain how you call AdapterDB class

Comment: I think you might have design issues. What if you create your database ( DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper (context);) from the main class and then call the constructor from the main class and send the object to the database from the main class

Answer (score 0):

your missing a fundamental Michelle -- you "write" a class then you declare a datatype of that class with a name to use it and call new on the same exact code you just wrote but use the variable name to address the func() calls in the code you wrote